# Do data transfer cost apply to access images from amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-product-api

Scenario is that I want to store my images uploaded by user through my application in amazon s3 and later retrieve them on demand.
So I was going through how much cost it will be there to store images in s3 and I across term "**Data transfer cost**",

I am bit confused like suppose I uploaded and image in s3 and make it public and when even I access that image suppose in a Brower tab through public s3 link, do I have to pay data transfer cost for that? or accessing and image from it's public link is free?

Same is if I download my image from s3 using my front end application, then also I have to pay data transfer cost?

**Second part of my question :**
If data transfer cost apply can I avoid my data transfer cost by first accessing my image from NodeJS running in ec2 instance then sending it back from my NodeJS application running in ec2 instance ?

Comment: The best people to ask whether Amazon will charge you for something are Amazon. Don't take advice from random strangers on the 'net that may leave you liable for fees you don't expect. Read Amazon's pricing and ask them for any clarifications you need.

Comment: (But yes, you'll be charged data transfer costs each time you or anyone else downloads those images from S3.)

Comment: can you tell me link where I can contact them directly i was not able to find it, Thanx in advance

Comment: In the top right of the AWS console you should have the option to open a support case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you pay in both cases, that is exactly what the data transfer cost means.
Additionally you pay for the storage and for the number of requests.

You can e.g. go through https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator to get a rough estimate of what cost you may incur.

No, you cannot avoid the cost. If you start loading them into the ec2 machine that cost is free (assuming same region etc.) but then transferring the data from the ec2 instances does cost again.

Comment: Yes sending from ec2 to user's will cost but I think this time it will be lower, am I right ?
like sending back in form of base64 as response

Comment: @GeetanshuGulati no, the cost is equivalent. S3 outbound pricing is the same as ec2 outbound pricing. But if you transmit them via your own instance you have to write a lot more code, spend the processing time, etc.

Comment: @GeetanshuGulati Wether base64 encoding the image and spending the time for that vs. the reduced transfer cost is an interesting topic... I would not do it. Instead you should put a cloudfront in front of the s3 bucket and that will gzip compress the data instead, which is generally preferred.

Comment: Note that base64 encoding is certainly more expensive than basically anything else since base64 is not storage-efficient, it wastes a lot of bytes by only using a very limited charset.